# Collapsable images inside pdf

Tags: image, pdf, interactive, collapsable

Is it possible to create a collapsible image (similar to reddit) inside a PDF document?

The book is around 500 pages and has many large images. Hyperlinking wouldn't work very well because it will have to lead the reader to another page. Going back and finding where you stopped can be annoying.

If this isn't possible, I'm open to other suggestions. The goal is streamlined reading and viewing images.

Comment: Most common readers support navigation to go back from the hyperlink target. Ie in Acrobat Reader from menu `View -> Go To -> Previous View`, shortcut `Alt+LeftArrow`. Linux's Document viewer has "Back" and "Foward" buttons next to page number. I trust other common readers support similar functionality. So perhaps hyperlinking is OK afterall.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment, you could insert buttons into the page with the images that use this system to go back to the view the reader came from. I might not be supported by all viewers but will be by the most common ones.